# How can I add/import/include 'IncludeController' in JSR223/Groovy and use it in current TestPlan?

Tags: performance, jmeter

How can I access/use the specific test fragment file (jmx file) in the project use JSR223/Groovy code and use a specific Sampler?

For example, I have test fragments files [patientApi.jmx, doctorApi.jmx], each of these include fragment contains bunch of HTTP Requests (endpoint) with assertions and etc.:
**patientApi.jmx:**

- {uri}/patientApi/getFirstName
- {uri}/patientApi/getLastName
- {uri}/patientApi/getDoctors
- {uri}/patientApi/blaBla

**doctorApi.jmx:**

- {uri}/doctorApi/getFirstName
- {uri}/doctorApi/getLastName
- {uri}/doctorApi/getPatients
- {uri}/doctorApi/blaBla

So, I would like to know can I import/add/include in my new TestPlan these test fragments and disabled/enabled specific HTTP requests. It will give me the ability to create different test suites.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is using an [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) per API endpoint and naming them according to the endpoint URL.

Once done you can put them under the [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and choose which one you want to execute by providing the relevant "Switch Value"

[image]

The "Switch value" doesn't have to be hard-coded, you can use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) there originating from i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)